# Running a Screensaver over a dual-monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display

I've recently been granted a dual-monitor setup (more of a sysadmin rather than programmer, not worried about having 3) but my screensaver only runs on the primary display. I've heard about DisplayFusion and Ultramon but they are both paid software and I would have thought Windows 7 would be "intelligent" enough to do this.

I'm using the [MatrixGL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matrixgl/) Screensaver, not sure if this would make any difference.

Now I need to find some good multi-monitor desktops, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using [Matrix KS](http://www.kellysoftware.com/ssaver/matrix_ks.asp). Thanks to @Psychoholic for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

[Electric sheep](http://electricsheep.org) - amazing graphics, free, multi-monitor support.

Comment: Seen this, does look awesome. If I can't get my screensaver to work then this is they way I'll go.

Comment: Matrix KS has long been my favorite Matrix-type screensaver.  To get it to fill multiple monitors you need to fuss with the settings to specify your entire desktop resolution, but once that's done, it' quite nice.

Comment: @Psychoholic, you should have set that comment as an answer, then I would have accepted it. Downloaded, installed and works straight away.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably an issue with your preferred screen saver. the default windows screen savers do work properly on multiple monitors. you might submit a bug report on Sourceforge to let the developer know that (at least in Windows 7) it does not support multiple monitors.

Comment: I'll take a look at the screensaver suggested by Psychoholic below, and then I'll submit a report too. Good Idea, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

UltraMon works for screensaver for multimonitor in windows 7!

change the screensaver to UltraMon and click Settings...

Ultramon will detect all your monitors and you change the screensaver for each screen.

I changed mine to Ribbons for all four monitors and it spans accorss each monitor as if it was just one!

Answer (score 1):

Most 3D applications can not span monitors due to limitations of the 3d card/driver.  Switch to a 2d screen saver and you should be all set.