# Multimonitor screensavers?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, screensaver

I am currently using Windows 7 64 bit, with 2 screens. I am attempting to make my first screen saver. I am aware that a screensaver is essentially just a .exe renamed to .scr. I currently have a screensaver created using GameMaker 8.1, and is essentially just a game with no controls that has its width and height set to my screen. It works fine for single monitor computers, however, no matter what I do, it refuses to stretch to encompass my second monitor.

Does anyone know of way to have this screensaver stretch across the 2 screens? It doesn't matter if your method is by using a different programming language, 3rd party programs or anything. I just want to get this working.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you open the window when your screen saver starts? What dimensions do you provide?

Comment: Sounds like a SE question, provided you share some code and how you have tried this. In .NET it should be as easy as setting width and height to the virtual screen's bounds, and left, top @ 0,0...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a Screensaver over a dual-monitor setup](http://superuser.com/questions/209689/running-a-screensaver-over-a-dual-monitor-setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Following on a little bit from @AthomSfere's comment, I simply rewrote my screensaver in WPF, and set the window's dimensions to be full screen. If anyone requires a greater explanation of this method, please do not hesitate to comment.